# Expected Value Via ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I recently learned about a technique to use ODEs to find the mathematical expectation. I decided to apply it to the following problem:

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots\simeq$ Uniform$(0,1)$ iid. Let $N$ be the first index $n$ where $X_n\neq \max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$. Find $E[N]$.

To solve, we generalize the problem by defining a function $m(z)$. The function $m(z)$ is the expected number of uniform variables needed so that the monotonic condition no longer holds when initially starting at $z$. Specifically, it is the average of the first index $n$ such that $X_n<X_{n-1}\geq\ldots X_1\geq z$. Then the total law of expectation - where we condition on $X_1$ - yields

$$m(x) = \int^1_x(1+m(z)) \mathrm{d}z$$

For now, let us assume that $m(x)$ is differentiable. Then differentiating both sides yields

$$m'(x)=-(1+m(x))$$
or
$$m'(x)+m(x)=-1$$

This is a linear ODE with general solution $m(x)=ce^{-x}-1$. Plugging this equation back into the integral shows that

$$\int^1_z(1+m(z))\;\mathrm{d}z=-ce^{-1}+ce^{-z}=ce^{-x}+1$$

or $c=e$. All the remains to do is to evaluate at $x=0$:

$$m(0)=e^{1-0}-1=e-1$$

However, solving it through alternative means, I obtain $e$. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather*}
m(x)= E[N\mid X_1>x]=\frac{1}{1-x}\int^1_x E[N\mid X_1=z]dz=\\
=\frac{1}{1-x}\int^1_x \left(E[N\mid X_1=z, X_2<X_1]z +E[N\mid X_1=z, X_2\geq X_1](1-z) \right)dz=\\
=\frac{1}{1-x}\int^1_x \left(2z +(1+m(z))(1-z)\right)dz
\end{gather*}
Differentiating:
$$(1-x)m'(x)= xm(x)-x-1$$
Whose solution is:
$$m(x)=\frac{e^{1-x}-x}{1-x}$$

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. If that was indeed $m(x)$, then $m(x)\rightarrow 2$ as $x\rightarrow 1$. But the surely the expected value is intuitively $1$ since $X_1<1$ almost surely?

Comment: According to the problem statement, N can never be 1.